# Third time's a charm...maybe

Tags: javascript

I'm still trying to gather information from cells, perform a function with the information, and then return the result to a different cell. I know it's possible, but I'm having a hellofatime trying to figure it out. Many of the hints I have received here have led me down paths where I found a nugget of information expressed in a way that I understood it. I hope this will happen again- this is driving me nuts.
The following code has been tested on Liveweave and no errors were shown. It still doesn't work though. Any ideas why?

**JAVACSCRIPT**

```
calculate = function(){
var total1= (document.form[0].mark1.value) +(document.form[0].mark2.value) + (document.form[0].mark3.value);
  document.form[0].total.value = total1;
  return total1;
};
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <table>




    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Final</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Name1</td>
      <td class="mark1">34</td>
      <td class="mark2">77</td>
      <td class="mark3">99</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td class="total" placeholder="0">0</td>
    </tr>
  </table><br/>
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate"/>
<!-- End your code here -->
  </form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers,
Peter

Comment: Could/would you be able to use jQuery? I have done something similar to this (successfully) but with jQuery and I don't know how to accomplish it using pure JS.

Comment: @LGT JQuery is on my list of things to learn. At the moment, I'm barely getting my brain wrapped around the JS :)

Comment: `document.form` will never do anything -- [`document.forms`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_doc_forms.asp) will return the collection of forms in the document (but still won't do what you want, because as explained by @T.J.Crowder you can't access table cell contents in this way.)

Comment: @PeterJ: FWIW, what you're doing at the moment is two things: Learning JavaScript, and quite separately, learning the DOM API (`document.forms`, `querySelector`, etc.). So LGT's suggestion comes down to suggesting that you learn JavaScript and jQuery's API instead of JavaScript and DOM's API. There's no clear strong reason to do that presented by your question, and the advantage of the DOM API is that it's on all browsers (with varying degrees of correctness), whereas you can only use jQuery if you include it on the page. But jQuery makes some things simpler, which may be useful when learning.

Answer (score 1):

The only DOM elements that have a `value` property are form fields (`<input>`, `<textarea>`, `<select>`). You don't have any in your example, so you can't use `value` to get them.

Similarly, you can't access an element with a class name by using `container.theClass`, so `document.form[0].mark1` won't give you the `<td class="mark1">...</td>` cell in your table in your form.

To access elements, the main tools are:

- [`querySelector`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/#queryselector) - Find the first element matching a CSS selector in a container
- [`querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api2/#queryselectorall) - Find all elements matching a CSS selector in a container
- [`document.getElementById`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) - Find the one element with the given `id` value

To get the *text* (not value) within non-form cells, you can use `innerHTML` (which gives you HTML markup, but in your case, that's just the text of the numbers). Then we parse that text to get numbers.

In your example, then, we can find the elements we care about using `document.querySelector(".mark1")` and similar.

```
function calculate(){
    var mark1 = document.querySelector(".mark1");
    var mark2 = document.querySelector(".mark2");
    var mark3 = document.querySelector(".mark3");
    var total = document.querySelector(".total");
    var sum   = parseInt(mark1.innerHTML, 10) +
                parseInt(mark2.innerHTML, 10) +
                parseInt(mark3.innerHTML, 10);
    total.innerHTML = String(sum);
}
```

Note that this assumes that you will only ever want to use the first (only) cells. If you had multiple form/tables and wanted to work within each of them, you'd want to do it slightly differently, perhaps by passing the form element into the function:

```
function calculate(form){
    var mark1 = form.querySelector(".mark1");
    var mark2 = form.querySelector(".mark2");
    var mark3 = form.querySelector(".mark3");
    var total = form.querySelector(".total");
    var sum   = parseInt(mark1.innerHTML, 10) +
                parseInt(mark2.innerHTML, 10) +
                parseInt(mark3.innerHTML, 10);
    total.innerHTML = String(sum);
}
```

Note how I used `form.querySelector` rather than `document.querySelector`. This finds the first matching element, but only looking *within* the form. So if we had three forms, we could do this:

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form"); // Note the "All"
var index;
for (index = 0; index < forms.length; ++index) {
    calculate(forms[index]);
}
```

[Live copy with three forms](http://jsbin.com/guqoqo/1) *(source at end of answer)*

This is the reason for using classes rather than `id`s. `id`s are useful for things that will be **unique** on the page, but in general prefer to use classes for flexibility.

---

Side point: Note how I changed how the function was being created. The above is the normal way to *declare* a function. What you were doing was another way, which creates the function using an expression and assigns it to a variable. But you didn't declare the variable, and so your code fell prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). If you prefer to use an expression, declare the variable:

```
var calculate = function(){
    var mark1 = document.querySelector(".mark1");
    var mark2 = document.querySelector(".mark2");
    var mark3 = document.querySelector(".mark3");
    var total = document.querySelector(".total");
    var sum   = parseInt(mark1.innerHTML, 10) +
                 parseInt(mark2.innerHTML, 10) +
                 parseInt(mark3.innerHTML, 10);
    total.innerHTML = String(sum);
};
```

---

Source of the three forms example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>First form</p>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Final</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td class="mark1">34</td>
        <td class="mark2">77</td>
        <td class="mark3">99</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>  
  <p>Second form</p>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Final</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td class="mark1">4</td>
        <td class="mark2">7</td>
        <td class="mark3">18</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>  
  <p>Third form</p>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Final</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Name1</td>
        <td class="mark1">1</td>
        <td class="mark2">2</td>
        <td class="mark3">3</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td class="total">0</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>  
  <div><input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate"></div>
<script>
  function calculate(form){
    var mark1 = form.querySelector(".mark1");
    var mark2 = form.querySelector(".mark2");
    var mark3 = form.querySelector(".mark3");
    var total = form.querySelector(".total");
    var sum   = parseInt(mark1.innerHTML, 10) +
                parseInt(mark2.innerHTML, 10) +
                parseInt(mark3.innerHTML, 10);
    total.innerHTML = String(sum);
  }

  var forms = document.querySelectorAll("form"); // Note the "All"
  var index;
  for (index = 0; index < forms.length; ++index) {
    calculate(forms[index]);
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: We don't have to make it a string at the end `total.innerHTML = sum`

Comment: @soktinpk: We don't *have* to, because it will happen implicitly. I was emphasizing the fact we're dealing with strings.

Comment: Very detailed. Thank you. I now have hours more "trying to figure it out" time ahead of me. I'm slow that way. Thanks very much for your answer.

Comment: @PeterJ: No worries, have fun! I've added an example showing the code applied to three forms on the same page (the value of using classes rather than `id`s).

Answer (score 0):

use id to use with `document.getElementById('id').innerHTML`

```
 var totalsum= parseInt(+document.getElementById('mark1').innerHTML) +      
parseInt(+document.getElementById('mark2').innerHTML) + 
  parseInt(+document.getElementById('mark3').innerHTML);


document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = totalsum.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to achieve is a form with user-changeable fields, rather than just a table, then you need to insert named `input`s into your html table cells:

```
<td><input name="mark1" type="number" value="34" /></td>
```

You can then access your form's properties in javascript, in the way that you are trying to do:

```
calculate = function () {
    var form = document.forms[0];
    form.total.value = Number(form.mark1.value) + Number(form.mark2.value) + Number(form.mark3.value);
});
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N2R3U/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I just had to see if I could do it with Javascript. This solution works on the first form found, all rows except the first one separately and all cells except the first and last on each row. You can play around with the selectors for your needs.

Oh, and the reason for suggesting this solution is that it's dynamic – great if you don't know the number of columns or rows generated. Also, you can set classes on the cells you want to include in the calculations and the total/sum cells for simpler selection and IE compatibility.

```
function calculate() {
    // Select the first form.
    var form = document.querySelector("form");
    // Select all rows, except the first one, in the form.
    var rows = form.querySelectorAll("tr:not(:first-child)");
    for (var row_index = 0; row_index < rows.length; row_index++) {
        var sum = 0;
        // Select all cells, except the first and last ones, in the row.
        var cells = rows[row_index].querySelectorAll("td:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)");
        for (var cell_index = 0; cell_index < cells.length; cell_index++) {
            sum += parseInt(cells[cell_index].textContent, 10);
        }
        var total = rows[row_index].querySelector("td:last-child");
        total.textContent = sum;
    }
}
```

Also, note the function call () in `<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate()" />`.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/47Ngg/

Comment: Thanks LGT, but where did you test this? I can't seem to get it to work on liveweave or JSfiddle

Comment: I take that back. Very interesting solution!

Comment: OK, I pretty much get how your solution works. I've been trying to modify it so that the .textContent is a user input. In other words, a teacher needs to be able to input marks. Here's what I came up with, but now the calculation returns NaN.  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/47Ngg/)

Comment: You have to click "Update" to get a new link or I'll just see my saved code there. :(

Comment: The link I posted was to the attempted adapted version.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/A9Yb9/1/ Changed **placeholder** to **value**, cell selector to **"td > input"** and total selector to **".total"**. Also, **id** values should be unique on each page. Don't forget to close your input tags with slash at the end.

Comment: Thanks, LGT!! You da bomb!